# How to set shell from system function?

Tags: c++, string, shell

In a c++ program I am using system function to execute ldapsearch command to get the data in a file. But the problem happen when the shell is bash the string passed to ldapsearch results into an error and it work fine if the default shell for the user is csh. When I debug the code I observed below string is passed as command

```
ldapsearch -h <hostname> -p <port> -D <binddn> -w <passwd> -b \"cn=admin root\" \"(filter)\" cn
```

Now two solution I can think of

1. Set the shell to csh before calling system function.
2. Or remove "\" from the above string so that any shell can understand the command.

Any pointer in this regard will be great. Here one thing to be noted that I am using std::string to create the final output string below is the snippet of the same.

```
std::string ldapSystemCmd;
if(!ldapCosSearchDn.empty()) {
    ldapSystemCmd += ldapInitialString;
    ldapSystemCmd += "-b \"" + ldapCosSearchDn + "\"";
}
ldapSystemCmd += " \"" + ldapCosSearchFilter + "\"";
ldapSystemCmd += " cn >" + ldapSearchFileName;
int systemOutput = system(ldapSystemCmd.c_str());
```

Or if there is anyother way I can achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `\"` with `'` and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `fork` + `execlp` (or `spawnl` on windows) functions or their neighbors. This way you wouldn't need to escape your arguments, because you will call that program directly without using shell.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that the command string contains backslashes, rather I think you misinterpreted the debugger output. The problem could lie in the characters of *port*, *binddn* or *passwd*; try quoting them, too, if they contain punctuation marks.